# MSDB - Backup information is not updating

Tags: sql-server, backup

I'am having a problem in my database

My backup job is working correctly, but the tables of `msdb` is not updating the information.

Here is my case, if you see, My last transaction log backup was in 2020/05/23 05:00:00 in my job history:

[image]

But in the msdb tables like `msdb.dbo.backupset` and `msdb.dbo.backupediafamily` is not updating.. the last backup was in 2020/05/22 01:00:00:

[image]

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Have you checked if the backup files are being created despite the job reporting success? What is the version of SQL Server?

Comment: I've just check, There is backup there. Everything is normal, but my monitoring tool is warning that there is no backup because it use the views in msdb to check if is stiil doing backup.

Comment: You didn't say your SQL Server version. Have you checked if there's any error log during the time of the backup? maybe the action of registering the new line on `msdb.dbo.backupset` and `msdb.dbo.backupediafamily` doesn't trigger an error to fail the backup, but logs some information about not registering the new backup made. Could it be that you're not [deleting the old history](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-delete-backuphistory-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and there's no space for the database to grow?

Comment: It's working again. I really don't know what happened and I did nothing to work again.. but I had space and the version is SQL 2012 Enterprise edition.

Comment: Take this opportunity to migrate off Maintenance Plans and into something more flexible, more "intelligent" (doesn't just re-index the whole database every time, just performs the necessary maintenance) and transparent (with better logging to boot), like [Ola Hallengren's Maintenance Solution](https://ola.hallengren.com/).

Answer (score 1):

As you are running SQL Server 2012 it might be [this bug](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/951288/sql-server-records-a-backup-operation-in-the-backupset-history-table-w).

Check also this article: ["Could not insert a backup or restore history/detail record in the msdb database" While restoring msdb](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/80063/could-not-insert-a-backup-or-restore-history-detail-record-in-the-msdb-database)